# Find all nonnegative integer solutions to $2^a +3^b +5^c =n!$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, exponentiation, factorial

Question: Find all nonnegative integer solutions to $2^a +3^b +5^c =n!$.

My work so far: I realize that if $n$ is greater than $2, 3$, or $5$, then $3^b+5^c$ has to be divisible by $2$, $2^a+5^c$ has to be divisible by $3$, and $2^a+3^b$ has to be divisible by $5$. I'm not sure how to prove that the sum of these powers equals $n!$ exactly.

Comment: Discussion at [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1947083p13425083)

Comment: @VIVID Thanks! I will check it out.